# Using Swagger for Express alongside normal routes

Tags: api, node.js, rest, express, swagger

I'm interested in using something like swagger-node-express to build the API for the project I'm working on. However, some parts of the app are non-api based (serving HTML instead). Has anyone got any ideas as to how I would use Swagger alongside normal routes?

Comment: Also interested in this approach.  How about defining the normal, HTML-serving routes in Swagger/OpenAPI as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll just need to make sure that your routes don't conflict with the Swagger routes, and your other routes will processed as usual. One easy way would be to make Swagger live under a subpath. Take a look at the docs on that score:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-node-express

```
var app = express();
var subpath = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use("/v1", subpath);

swagger.setAppHandler(subpath);
```

Otherwise, you could just keep an eye out to make sure that none of the other URLs you are using in your application conflict with the Swagger URLs, and you should be able to define your routes and handlers normally. E.g. you can use Swagger to serve up docs under `http://localhost:8002/api-docs.json/pet` but have `http://localhost:8002/foo/` do something else just by adding the route in the normal way:

```
app.get(/foo/, function(req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Foo\n');
})
```

Using the subpath configuration is probably the cleanest approach but you could also just keep track of the routes yourself and make sure that the Swagger routes aren't conflicting with the routes in the rest of your app.

Comment: Don't you think so it will create a duplicate code? in this case we need to write two middlewares for both  "/foo/" and "/v1/foo/". or is there any other way to do it?